# advice for google api use as a CDN for phoneGap application

Tags: cordova, google-drive-api, google-api-client

I would like to create a phoneGap application which will browse through items on a google drive account. The idea is that I can push out new documents to users of the application when necessary.

I don't want the users to have to authenticate against the account ideally the application will automatically authenticate.

1. Is it possible to create a google drive account in which access is not publicly available but available for all users of the phoneGap application and the administrator?
2. Can you think of a better way to achieve my desired result?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. You can't
2. Try Google App Engine,  Google Cloud Storage